# Shared Configuration and AppSettings

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, web.config

We use Shared Configuration for our IIS config, so the same config is used by the webservers. This works well.

We like to share some server-level `<AppSettings>` between the servers. (in IIS manager, select Server -> Application Settings) Will the `<AppSettings>` on server level are also shared with the Shared Configuration?

I can't find the `<AppSettings>` in applicationHost.config nor administration.config, so I think it won't be shared, but I also don't know where those server-level appsettings will be stored.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx <appSettings> should be in `web.config` files.